# how to exclude the zero data in an tuple dataframe with index

Tags: python

All: I tried to remove the zero data in my tuple data frame but can't make it. Can you please do me a favor?

My code:

```
mylist = [[0 for y in xrange(0, 10, 1)] for x in xrange(0, 10, 1)]
for i in xrange(0, 10, 2):
    for j in xrange(0, 10, 2):
        mylist[i][j] = '%s,%s'%(i,j)

print mylist

df = pd.DataFrame(mylist)

print df
```

I would like to have a (x,y) coordinates system created. Said origin is (0,0) the step of (x,y) is (2,4). I want to create a 10x 10 cooridnate list such as (0,0), (2,0)...(4,0) until (2*x,0) then loop to y (4, 0), (4,2)...(4, 2*x). Again, thanks for answers.

Comment: Where did you try to remove zero data? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated response:
First, remove the arrays of all zeros (following the for loops).

```
mylist = [x for x in mylist if not all([val == 0 for val in x])]
```

Then, remove the zeros that exist in the remaining arrays.

```
mylist = [[v for v in x if v != 0] for x in mylist]
```

This will create the following: [['0,0', '0,2', '0,4', '0,6', '0,8'], ['2,0', '2,2', '2,4', '2,6', '2,8'], ['4,0', '4,2', '4,4', '4,6', '4,8'], ['6,0', '6,2', '6,4', '6,6', '6,8'], ['8,0', '8,2', '8,4', '8,6', '8,8']].

You could also combine those two steps into one. May be slightly more time efficient, but looks a little messy.

```
[[v for v in x if v!=0] for x in mylist if not all([val==0 for val in x])]
```

---

To walk through your code, your first line creates an array of arrays, filled with 0's. You then have a for loop, which is in `xrange(0, 10, 2)`.

You have set the step of the outer for loop to equal 2. This means it will operate on every other array in `mylist`.

You inner for loop also has its step argument as `2`. As such, it will only operate on every other value in the specific array that you are on.

If you would like every single zero that you initially created to be replaced with your `%s,%s` string, simply change the last argument for each for loop to `1`. (i.e. `...xrange(0, 10, 1)`)

Comment: I don't understand how this addresses the post. This still includes `0` values and the closest I can get to understanding the desired output is that they shouldn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for answer but this is intentional. I try to make different step in this array (e.g, 2). So back to my question, if this is the case, how can I remove zero data in this array? Thanks!

Comment: @odom0905 can you please address my initial comment? The question is unanswerable unless you can be specific on what you want.

Comment: @roganjosh I have tried running the code, I do not see any 0 integer values remaining in the list? @ odom0905 so to clarify, you want to remove the 0 data in the arrays that you operated on (the ones with mixed 0 integers and strings), but you would like to leave the ones that you skipped alone (the ones that are all zeros)?

Comment: I don't understand. From your suggestion: `['0,0', '0,1', '0,2', '0,3', '0,4', '0,5', '0,6', '0,7', '0,8', '0,9'], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ['2,0', '2,1', '2,2', '2,3', '2,4', '2,5', '2,6', '2,7', '2,8', '2,9'], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]...]
` There's a _lot_ of `0` values in there. Either you haven't addressed the question or your proposed approach isn't clear at all.

Comment: @roganjosh, my suggestion results in [['0,0', '0,1', '0,2', '0,3', '0,4', '0,5', '0,6', '0,7', '0,8', '0,9'], ['1,0', '1,1', '1,2', '1,3', '1,4', '1,5', '1,6', '1,7', '1,8', '1,9'] ...]. There are no arrays of zero integers remaining, if you change both xrange steps to 1. Either way, it does not seem like either of us are sure exactly what the poster is trying to achieve.

Comment: Please let me explain what exactly I want: I would like to have a (x,y) coordinates system created. Said origin is (0,0) the step of (x,y) is (2,4). I want to create a 10x 10 cooridnate list such as (0,0), (2,0)...(4,0) until (2*x,0) then loop to y (4, 0), (4,2)...(4, 2*x). Again, thanks for answers.

Comment: @odom0905 updated the answer, is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I want. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @odom0905 please do mark the answer as correct (the green tick) if this solved your problem!